# Do you need to oil the bushings in a doweling jig?

Tags: powertools

I got a second-hand doweling jig with no directions. It just seems wrong to spin a drill bit inside the bushing without some lubrication. I found several sites that don't say anything then one that suggested a few drops of oil; that reinforced my suspicion and shook my confidence in the non-oil sites.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question for the [woodworking site](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions), but I would not oil the guide, the oil will stain the wood. Do use care while using the guide, use sharp drill bits that will not need to be forced to hard to drill. The more force you use the better the chance of angling the bit in the guide, wearing it out prematurely, and making the dowel go in holes that are not in line with each other. Brad point bits are preferred here. Purchase [drill stops](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0055HPIWS) too, if you don't already have them...

Comment: Just to add, oil can compromise your glue joint.